# How to apply GPOs without having to relog users?

Tags: migration, group-policy

hI,

I am using Windows Server 2008 and I have to do a final migration from the Windows 2000 Server (demoted long ago).  I have to transfer group, public and user files on the new server.

The only question I got about this is because since I am changing servers and the GPOs are attached to the old server shares in the GPOs, how can I change users' network drives pointers thru GPOs without anmy intervention on their computers, not even a relog, so I can avoid any form of downtime?

ie : I wanna change the pointer of the personal user's U: drive without asking the user to relog or even notice it.  I'm going to change it from \OLDSERVER\users\%username% to \NEWSERVER\u\%username%

I know that there is DFS that avoids this thing and it's gonna be implemented after the migration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have DFS I don't think their is any way that you are going to change drive mappings with a GPO without the user noticing.

You might be able to make this with a [DNS aliases](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias), but as I understand it, you have to apply a change to all the clients first that will require a reboot.

Comment: A change to client computers to use an alias name? Is this something new? I've done aliases for a goodly number of years w/o problems. Perhaps somethings different in these new-fangled Vista / Windows 2008 OS's re: aliases that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Just have the users logoff and logon again. You're trying to make this too complicated for not a lot of payoff. I'm all for doing things transparently but there's a point of diminishing returns (and you could've done this in a way as to have the new server computer end up with the same name as the old server computer, but you didn't).

You *can* use a NetBIOS alias. You don't need to make any changes to clients (see [How to Configure Windows Machine to Allow File Sharing with DNS Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias) for a pretty good writeup) in order to use it to my knowledge.