# How do you serve multiple network names with W2k8 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am new to Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, my past experience is with W2k3. This question is about changing our development environment from a pair of clustered W2k3 Ent. servers over to a new single W2k8 Ent. server.

On our W2k3 environment, we have a variety of network names served up as Network Name resources from within Cluster Administrator. Worked like a champ.

In W2k8 Ent., is there a way to serve up multiple network names without having to set up a cluster environment? (gut feeling wonders if it's just a case of serving up names in DNS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you need : pure DNS alias or a SMB (CIFS) alias.

If you need a CIFS alias the netdom.exe command will work wonder.

```
netdom computername /add:mynewalias

netdom computername /enum
```

The /setprimary and /remove switches are useful when renaming.

It will register a DNS alias AND a SMB alias. Reboot may be required for everything to work smoothly (maybe useless since 2k8)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way would be to add CNAME records in DNS

Comment: Keep it simple.

Comment: This isn't enough to serve CIFS / SMB on multiple names, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just talking about serving the CIFS file and print sharing protocol with various "alias" names have a look at [How to Configure Windows Machine to Allow File Sharing with DNS Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias).

For other protocols it may be a matter of creating a CNAME record in DNS or, if the protocol is "name aware" (like, say, HTTP with host headers) you may need to do some protocol level configuration.