# display DNS Alias a a physical machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, alias

How can I display a DNS Alias as a physical machine in the list of available computers when I open the network window.

I have applied this procedure ([How to Configure Windows Machine to Allow File Sharing with DNS Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias)) with no success.

The Alias  is accessible if I type it \Alias_Name\ after that I can browse the directory structure

Answer (score 3):

The final answer is "You cannot do this" from the windows "Network" icon. That list is populated by NetBIOS. The alias that you've created is in DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You've left out a bunch of information but I'll take a guess here... it sounds like you're browsing the network via an icon. This process of connecting resources, at least at one point was done using NetBIOS and the "Computer Browser" service. It might be different in a domain, but the point I'm making is that this process won't know a thing about that DNS alias. SAMBA on a linux host might be able to do what you ask, but Windows will probably not.

Comment: After reviewing the other link you referenced, it does look like that should take care of you. I think perhaps you may need to give it some time to update, or may require a reboot for some of those setting to take effect. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?