# Cannot connect to shared printer via cname record

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, network-printer

I'm trying to share a printer from a server using a cname record with that server. I can connect to the printer share just fine if I use the actual host name for the server, but it giv.es me an error if I try to connect via the cname:

> Windows couldn't connect to the printer. Check the printer name and try again. If this is a network printer, make sure that the printer is turned on, and the printer address is correct.

I have seen and tried everything suggested in this related question, including manually setting SPNs, with no luck:

> [How to Configure Windows Machine to Allow File Sharing with DNS Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add "DNS on the Wire" on the print server.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print /v DnsOnWire /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Reference: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverprint/thread/00eeb192-d03a-4d1b-9066-427fc678ae97

Comment: This did the trick after a restart. As a bonus, I added this information to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but surely all you'd have to do is set a CNAME record in the DNS Server  pointing to either the server e.g. printserver.domain.local or create an A record so that printer.domain.local points to the IP address of the printer.. making sure that your client machines' DNS IP settings are pointing to the DNS server and not a default gateway router!